# What is the matching template name for a given data-template-name

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, grunt-ember-templates

I am precompiling my templates using [grunt-ember-templates](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates). This tool is putting my templates in the `Ember.TEMPLATES` array, as expected. I am finetuning the configuration of `grunt-ember-templates`. For that I would like to know what is the expected key in the `Ember.TEMPLATES` array. Let's say I have this template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="phones/index">
    ....
</script>
```

Currently I have this template in a file called `app/templates/phones_index.hbs`, and `grunt-ember-templates` is putting the pre-compiled template in `Ember.TEMPLATES["app/templates/phones_index"]`, but this is wrong.

What is the expected key for `data-template-name="phones/index"`?

Comment: I believe you should compile the contents of `app/templates` directory, ignoring the directory segment in file names, so you don't get it translated into the template name. Ideally `phones/index.hbs` should translate into `App.TEMPLATES["phones/index"]`. Note that `_` is used for partials (e.g.: `phones/_form.hbs` for a general purpose form linked to the phone resource) so it might not be a good idea to use it in templates other than partial templates. I'm not the best person on Grunt tho, so I can't really tell how you should do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the key in `Ember.TEMPLATES` should be "phones/index".

You can configure grunt-ember-templates to drop the first part of your path and leave everything after `app/templates/` which will give you the correct key assuming you place your template inside of file `app/templates/phones/index.hbs`.  Using this set up, the key for the `app/templates/phones/index.hbs` file will be `Ember.TEMPLATES['phones/index']`, which is the same as having an uncompiled `<script>` tag with `data-template-name="phones/index"`.

Gruntfile.js (same as the Gruntfile.js in [this](https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences) project):

```
ember_templates: {
  options: {
    templateName: function(sourceFile) {
      return sourceFile.replace(/app\/templates\//, '');
    }
  },
  'dependencies/compiled/templates.js': ["app/templates/**/*.hbs"]
},
```

Comment: Way simpler than I thought +1

Comment: Thanks. I will then put all phone-related templates in an `app/templates/phones` directory. But then I have a problem: where to put the template related to `data-template-name="phone"`, or to `data-template-name="phone/edit"`?

Comment: An another question: you say "which is the same as having an uncompiled <script> tag with data-template-name="phones/index"". should I remove the `data-template-name` from the script tag when moving to pre-compiled templates? Will the `data-template-name` be inferred from the template file name?

Comment: you would place `data-template-name="phone"` into `app/templates/phone.hbs` and `data-template-name="phone/edit"` into `app/templates/phone/edit.hbs`. Any directory structure besides the `app/templates/` will be used in the key name.

Comment: your `*.hbs` files will not have any `<script>` tags in them, you should only place the contents of the template inside.  For example: https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences/blob/master/app/templates/application.hbs, and yes the key name is determined by the file path/file name after the `app/templates/`